# Reason why SQLite query returns the wrong value with sum

Tags: database, sqlite

I've come across a weird behavior in SQLite when running a query and I'd like to understand why the behavior happens.

When I run the following query the discount is calculated incorrectly making the summed value incorrect.

```
SELECT sum (quantity * price) - (sum (quantity * price)*(discount/100)) as total
FROM [orderProducts]
JOIN [order] ON [order].id = orderProducts.order_id
```

When the discount is 0, the query behaves as expected i.e the order total is summed correctly. However when there is a set discount the total value isn't correct. The discount seems to get applied at random to the rows when the sum happens. I get the correct behavior when I do do some creative grouping

```
SELECT sum (total) FROM (SELECT sum (quantity * price) - (sum (quantity * price)*(discount/100)) as total
FROM [orderProducts]
JOIN [order] ON [order].id = orderProducts.order_id
GROUP BY [order].id)
```

So my question is why does this make such a big difference? What is happening in the first query that makes the discount apply seemingly at random?

To test the queries you can use this statement to make the tables

```
create table orderProducts 
(
id int NOT NULL,
order_id NOT NULL,
quantity int(3),
price double NOT NULL,
primary key (id),
foreign key (order_id) references [order]
);

create table order
(
id int NOT NULL,
discount double NOT NULL,
primary key (id)
);
```

And to add data you can use

```
insert into order (id, discount) values (1, 10.0);
insert into order (id, discount) values (2, 0.0);

insert into orderProducts (id, order_id, quantity, price) values (1, 1, 1, 20);
insert into orderProducts (id, order_id, quantity, price) values (2, 2, 1, 50);
```

The expected output running the sum query is 68 but the actual output is 70

Comment: Show your table definitions and sample data (As sql create table and insert statements for easy importing), and the results you want to get from that data.

Comment: But I bet the issue is that discount is a column with integer affinity, so you're doing integer division, when you want floating point.

Comment: @shawn I've added the table and insert queries for you

Comment: Using sql keywords as column names is a royal pain... anyways, a `double` type translates to a sqlite `real` affinity, so so much for that particular idea. (I got 63.0 as a result of your first query, btw...)

Comment: I'm not sure why but the first query seems to pick ways of applying the discount at random. When I run that query I get 70. Your's seems to be applying the discount to both rows (10% of 50 + 10% of 20) and mine to neither

Comment: discount being outside of an aggregate function in an aggregate query means that the row that's used for that value is arbitrary. Different versions picking different rows to use, probably.

Comment: `select sum(quantity * price * (100 - discount) / 100) as total`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect to get 68 from your sample data, this does the trick:

```
SELECT sum(quantity * price) - sum((quantity * price) * (discount / 100)) AS total
FROM orderProducts
JOIN "order" ON "order".id = orderProducts.order_id;
```

Your original query uses `sum(quantity * price) * (discount / 100)` - that is, it multiplies the sum of all rows totals by a percentage, instead of multiplying each row's total by that row's discount percentage and totalling those numbers up.

Also note my use of double quotes around the `order` table name instead of brackets; quotes are the normal, standard SQL way of escaping identifiers; brackets are a MS-SQL thing that Sqlite supports for some degree of compatibility.